# Lines in Data Table

Tags: tables

Below is the code I've written for a data table I want to create:

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Time (t)} & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Position (cm)} & \multirow{2}{*}{SDOM}\\
& Trial 1 & Trial 2 & Trial 3 & Average & \\ \hline
0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00\\ \hline
%more data here
\end{tabular}
```

Currently it produces

[image: output].

I want to have a line above the trials/average obviously. Anyone know a way to do this?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Put `\cline{2-5}` after the first row? If that doesn't do it for you, then post a complete [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that).

Answer (score 4):

As @frabjous has already pointed out in a comment, you may achieve your formatting objective by inserting the instruction `\cline{2-5}` immediately after `\multirow{2}{*}{SDOM}\\`.

That said, do also consider giving your table a much more open and inviting "look" by (a) getting rid of all vertical rules -- trust me, they won't be missed -- and (b) replacing the basic-LaTeX directives `\hline` and `\cline` with some of the user macros of the [booktabs package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs/): `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\bottomrule`, and `\cmidrule`. Your readers are much more likely to spend time looking an attractively styled table than at an object that's as appealing as a prison cell window -- with lots of vertical and horizontal bars...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow, % for \multirow macro
            booktabs, % \toprule, \midrule, \bottomrule, \cmidrule macros
            amsmath,  % \smash[b] macro
            array,    % 'w' column type
            calc}     % \widthof macro
\newcommand{\mytab}[1]{%
   \smash[b]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}}
\begin{document}

\centering

\begin{tabular}{| *{6}{c|} }
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Time (t)} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Position (cm)} & \multirow{2}{*}{SDOM}\\
\cline{2-5}
& Trial 1 & Trial 2 & Trial 3 & Average & \\ 
\hline
0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00\\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{@{} c *{4}{wc{\widthof{Trial 1}}} c @{}}
%% (the 'w' column type takes a width argument)
\toprule
\mytab{Time\\(s)} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Position (cm)} & SDOM \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-5}
& Trial 1 & Trial 2 & Trial 3 & Avg.  \\ 
\midrule
0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00\\ 
0.10 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00\\ 
0.22 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You may liked solution with use of the `tabularray` package. Similarly as is in the @Mico answer (+1), proposed are two examples:

- with vertical in horizontal lines
- only with really needed horizontal rules defined in `booktabs` package and `S` columns defined in the `siunitx` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}
\centering

\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {l *{5}{c}}
             }
\SetCell[r=2]{c}    Time (t)
        &   \SetCell[c=4]{c}    Position (cm)
                    &           &           &           &   \SetCell[r=2]{c}    SDOM    \\
        & Trial 1   & Trial 2   & Trial 3   & Average   &                               \\
0.00    & 0.00      & 0.00      & 0.00      & 0.00      & 0.00                          \\
\end{tblr}

\bigskip
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {*{6}{Q[c, si={table-format=1.2}]}},
             row{1,2}= {guard}
             }
    \toprule
\SetCell[r=2]{c}    Time (t)
        &   \SetCell[c=4]{c}    Position (cm)
                    &           &           &           &   \SetCell[r=2]{c}    SDOM    \\
    \hline
        & Trial 1   & Trial 2   & Trial 3   & Average   &                               \\
    \midrule
0.00    & 0.00      & 0.00      & 0.00      & 0.00      & 0.00                          \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for your answer as well. :-)

Answer (score 2):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}
{
colspec={llllll},
cell{1}{1}={r=2}{c},
cell{1}{Z}={r=2}{c},
cell{1}{2}={c=4}{c},
cell{2}{2-5}={}{c},
hline{1-Z}={.03em},
vline{1-Z}={.03em}
}
Time (t) & Position (cm) &         &         &         & SDOM \\
         & Trial 1       & Trial 2 & Trial 3 & Average &      \\
0.00     & 0.00          & 0.00    & 0.00    & 0.00    & 0.00 \\
0.00     & 0.000000000   & 0.00    & 0.00    & 0.00    & 0.00 \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}
{
colspec={llllll},
cell{1}{1}={r=2}{c},
cell{1}{Z}={r=2}{c},
cell{1}{2}={c=4}{c},
cell{2}{2-5}={}{c},
hline{1,Z}={.08em},
hline{2}={.05em},
hline{3-Y}={.03em}
}
Time (t) & Position (cm) &         &         &         & SDOM \\
         & Trial 1       & Trial 2 & Trial 3 & Average &      \\
0.00     & 0.00          & 0.00    & 0.00    & 0.00    & 0.00 \\
0.00     & 0.000000000   & 0.00    & 0.00    & 0.00    & 0.00 \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]